# The expected value of an order statistic for normal random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, order-statistics

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be a random sample from normal distribution with mean equal to zero and variance $\sigma^2$. Prove $E[X_{(1)}]= \frac{-\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.

May I have to standarize the sample? Looks like it has a lot of tricky parts. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It is not clear what rools you have available. One can find the density function of $X_{(1)}$ in terms of the density and cdf of the normal, and then calculate the expectation in the "regular" way,

Comment: I'm confused with the integration part. I already have the pdf of $X_{(1)}$ but can't solve the integral. I try to use a relation that solve this part, but I don't get it.

Comment: OK, if I can manage it today I will write at least enough for you to finish.

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: You are welcome.  I had some time to type. To shortcircuit some unpleasantness, I used a little trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We start with a little trick. Let $Y$ be the minimum of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Then
$$Y=\frac{1}{2}\left(X_1+X_2-|X_1-X_2|\right).$$
Since the $X_i$ have mean $0$, we have
$$E(Y)=-\frac{1}{2}E(|X_1-X_2|).$$
The random variable $X_1-X_2$ is normally distributed mean $0$, variance $2\sigma^2$.

If $W$ is normal with this mean and variance, the mean of its absolute value is $2\int_0^\infty wg(w)\,dw$, where $g(w)$ is the density function of $w$. Thus
$$E(Y)=\int_0^\infty -wg(w)\,dw.$$
But
$$g(w)=\frac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-w^2/(4\sigma^2)).$$
To evaluate, make the substitution $u=w^2/(4\sigma^2)$. Then $du=\frac{w}{2\sigma^2}\,dw$, and we end up with
$$\int_0^\infty -\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-u}\,du.$$
This is $-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.